# Returning results where date column + days column < today's date

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

here's my question in detail
I have an invoice table, with date and payment_term column.

date is a date column
payment_term is an integer column, with the number of days an invoice is due for payment.

I'm trying to do a selectRaw in the Model (Fat Model, Skinny Controller thing)

```html
public static function sumOfInvoiceOverdue() {
  return Invoice::selectRaw('SUM(net_amount - paid_amount) as overdueAmount')->whereDate('date'+'payment_term', '<', Carbon::now())->get();
 }
```

So if I have an invoice date of 1st April
And it's due in 10 days

1/4/2020 + 10 = 11/4/2020
If Now is larger than 11/4/2020 it'll mean that this invoice is overdue, and should be returned as a result.

My question is, is it possible to do something like this?
whereDate('date'+'payment_term', '<', carbon:now())

Thank you, I've tried my best to google, and search, but the specifics of this question makes it rather hard for me to find an answer.

Much thanks again, and hope everyone is well in these trying times.

Edit: This is the result of what I wanted to work in SQL.

SELECT sum(net_amount - paid_amount) FROM `invoices` where date_add(`date`, INTERVAL `payment_term` DAY) < now()

I guess, if it's too much trouble in eloquent, I can fall back to raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

So happens, asking the right question will lead to the answer

In my own structuring of thoughts to ask a good question, it lead me to the following answer.

```
    public static function sumOfInvoiceOverdue() {
    return Invoice::selectRaw('SUM(net_amount - paid_amount) as overdueAmount')->whereRaw('date_add(`date`, INTERVAL `payment_term` DAY) < now()')->get();
}
```

Hope it helps others in the future. Cheers